# Identify the subsequent parents child hierarchy in table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a parent child relationship in a table. I would like to populate a new table using the parent child relationship table which would contain the child and all the subsequent parents in the hierarchy with the order.

I have been looking into the solutions provided but unable to write a query which provides me the desired result.

Below code can be used to create the table and load the sample data

```
create table DemoTable
(
    accountid bigint
    ,parentid bigint
    ,accountname nvarchar(128)
)
insert DemoTable(accountid,parentid,accountname)
select 1, null, 'Root'
union select 2, 1, 'Child1'
union select 3, 1, 'Child2'
union select 4, 1, 'Child3'
union select 5, 2, 'Child1.1'
union select 6, 2, 'Child1.2'
union select 7, 3, 'Child1.3'
union select 8, 7, 'Child1.3.7'
go
```

The output should look like below

```
accountid    parentid    hierarchyLevel
8    7    3
8    3    2
8    1    1
7    3    2
7    1    1
3    1    1
6    2    2
6    1    1
2    1    1
```

Comment: i don't understand how the `accountid` in you desired output is generated? why there is no **5** as `accountid`?

Comment: I took as sample for 8 and 6 account id. But yes 5 will also be there in the output as per the hierarchy.

Comment: Any suggestions anyone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can solve this by using [Common Table Expression (CTE)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

First we will take each child and climb up to their parents using recursive CTE. Initially, we denote each child's label as 1. Then, recursively we increment the number for their parents.

So, parents will have higher label value and child will have less.

Then we get the row number by partitioning using `accountId` in descending order of `label` values (because leaf has higher label value)

By doing these, we get our expected data. Then we have do some ordering to show it on the same way the expected output is shown in the question.

The code is given below and [here is the live dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7b999f87cd1ffa92ab01bb9b85ed5b90)

```
create table DemoTable
(
    accountid bigint
    ,parentid bigint
    ,accountname nvarchar(128)
)
insert DemoTable(accountid,parentid,accountname)
select 1, null, 'Root'
union select 2, 1, 'Child1'
union select 3, 1, 'Child2'
union select 4, 1, 'Child3'
union select 5, 2, 'Child1.1'
union select 6, 2, 'Child1.2'
union select 7, 3, 'Child1.3'
union select 8, 7, 'Child1.3.7'
go

;WITH ChildParentHierarchy AS
(
    SELECT accountId, parentId, 1 AS label
    FROM DemoTable WHERE parentid IS NOT NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT cte.accountId, D.parentId, (cte.label + 1) AS label
    FROM DemoTable D
    INNER JOIN ChildParentHierarchy cte
    ON D.accountid = cte.parentid
    WHERE D.parentid IS NOT NULL
)

SELECT
    accountId, 
    parentId, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        Partition BY accountId 
        ORDER BY label DESC
    ) AS hierarchyLevel
INTO #temp --we are storing the value of CTE
FROM ChildParentHierarchy
ORDER BY accountid DESC

--final result
SELECT * FROM #temp
ORDER BY accountid DESC, hierarchyLevel DESC

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Hope this will help you, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This may help....

```
DECLARE  @DemoTable table
(
    accountid bigint
    ,parentid bigint
    ,accountname nvarchar(128)
)
insert  @DemoTable(accountid,parentid,accountname)
select 1, null,    'Root'
union select 2, 1, 'Child1'
union select 3, 1, 'Child2'
union select 4, 1, 'Child3'
union select 5, 2, 'Child1.1'
union select 6, 2, 'Child1.2'
union select 7, 3, 'Child1.3'
union select 8, 7, 'Child1.3.7'

;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT accountid,parentid--,LEN(REPLACE(REPLACE(accountname,'.',''),'Child','')) hierarchyLevel
FROM @DemoTable
WHERE accountname <> 'Root'

UNION ALL

SELECT c.accountid ,d.parentid--,LEN(REPLACE(REPLACE(accountname,'.',''),'Child','')) hierarchyLevel
FROM @DemoTable d 
INNER JOIN CTE c ON d.accountid = c.parentid
WHERE d.accountname <> 'Root'

)
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION  BY accountid  ORDER BY accountid ASC ,parentid ASC) hierarchyLevel
FROM CTE
order by accountid DESC ,parentid DESC --, CAST(hierarchyLevel as INT) DESC
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Alam. I see that you have utilized the length ti identify the hierarchy level. What if that is not the case. This was sample data that I prepared but I cannot use the same concept with my actual data. Sorry about that. Otherwise I get the output what I am looking for.

Comment: Hi Alam, that worked for me. Can you please provide me some reference where I can learn SQl. This was very good.

Comment: You may follow  kudvenkat - YouTube and The book Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Bible.

Comment: @Sunil, if it is works for you then accept the answer .

Comment: Hello @KhairulAlam. That's a good approach to solve the above mentioned problem. +1 for that! Would you please tell me why you are using `option` here? Also, If the parent-to-child  accountIds are descending, how to calculated hierarchy level then?

Comment: option (maxrecursion 0) is used to avoid the error 'Recursive CTE error – The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion'.  If the parent-to-child accountIds are descending then have to change the query as per expectation .

Comment: Alam to find the hierarchy you are using the account id but what if is not in sort order ? what if tomorrow I get data in the below hirearchy level then it would not work.      DECLARE  @DemoTable table
(
    accountid bigint
    ,parentid bigint
    ,accountname nvarchar(128)
)
insert  @DemoTable(accountid,parentid,accountname)
select 1, null,    'Root'
union select 2, 1, 'Child1'
union select 3, 1, 'Child2'
union select 4, 1, 'Child3'
union select 5, 2, 'Child1.1'
union select 6, 2, 'Child1.2'
union select 10, 3, 'Child1.3'
union select 8, 10, 'Child1.3.7'

Comment: Alam I had accepted the solution but I just now reverted it as it was not generic. If the lower hirearchy has a higher value then it does not work. I have given  the sample data above. Sorry for the format as I am yet to understand the formatting of the forum

Comment: Show your expected result as per data given in comment section

Comment: This is how it should be now.    accountid  parentid  hierarchyLevel  
8  10   3  
8  3   2  
8  1  1  
10  3  2  
10  1  1  
3  1  1  
6  2  2  
6  1  1  
2  1  1    how do I format it ? Is there a way to load a picture ?

Comment: @Alam it should basically be the same as you showed in the table above just that 7 will be replaced with 10. Please let me know if you have got it.

Comment: Can you explain how the child account  come before the parent account ? 
`child 8 -- parent 10`

Comment: it can be what if child is and older employee in a company  (which is his employee id) and Manager has recently joined which would result in a higher Employee Number. The parent child relationship is provided to me by an external source over which I do not have any control.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196972/discussion-between-khairul-alam-and-sunil).

Answer (score 0):

You may try this solution (change the fields name as per your schema):

```
  WITH CTE AS (
      SELECT accountid, ParentId,0 AS [Level], CAST(accountid AS varchar(1000)) AS Heirarchy,accountid AS TopParentId
      FROM dbo.DemoTable
      WHERE accountid IN (SELECT accountid FROM DemoTable WHERE ParentId IS NULL)
      UNION ALL

      SELECT mgr.accountid, mgr.ParentId, CTE.[Level] +1 AS [Level], 
            CAST(( CAST(mgr.accountid AS VARCHAR(1000)) + '>' + CTE.Heirarchy) AS varchar(1000)) AS Heirarchy, CTE.TopParentId
      FROM CTE
        INNER JOIN dbo.DemoTable AS mgr
          ON CTE.accountid = mgr.ParentId
    )
    select  * from cte order by heirarchy desc
```

**EDIT**
Here heirarchy level is added to get the heirarchy relation of each id. It is not exactly what is needed but may be variant of this will help.

Comment: This is no what I am expecting as an output. This solution is available in many places and is not what I am looking for.

Comment: then explain what are you looking for?

Comment: Please check the output that I am looking for. I have provided the sample output. There should be as many rows for a child as there are hierarchy above the child with the order. In the above example the hierarchy for 8 is 8 ---> 7--->3--->1. So I need to have 3 rows of 8 reporting to each level as in the sample output above.